# <will do/ will have done>... by

Tags: perfect-constructions

There are these two constructions:

> will do... by...
> will have done... by...

I want to make sure I understand the difference, if any, between these them correctly and came up with these questions.

Someone promised in the past that:

1. I will finish the task by July.
2. I will have finished the task by July.

If he finished on June, 30th, he finished on time in both cases.

What if he finished on July 2nd？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking forward from the present time to completing the task in the future, you would usually use 1. It's a simple statement of intent.

But if you imagine that you are looking back on the completed task from a point in the future, you would use 2, often by way of a reflection of giving someone an assurance.

If, for example, you are reassuring an anxious householder about when you **will have finished** repainting, you are likely to use 2.

It's a question of whether you are looking forward or looking backward from some imaginary point in the future.

Much of the time, both are applicable.

We often say things like: **This time next year I will have finished my degree**, especially when we fondly imagine the future.

In your example you would need to specify **by the beginning of July**.

When/whether the job was finished is not relevant. Both sentences are making statements about when it will be finished, but from different perspectives.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand you correctly,  do you mean the expression "by July"  is not clear as to whether it's by the **beginning or end** of July？

Comment: @Robbyzhu Yes, or any other time in July.